# Uploading video to firebase from camera roll iOS Swift 5

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have been trying to upload a video from the camera role to firebase but it is not working.

I am getting error code **-1** in the console:

> <1> finished with error [-1] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1 "unknown error"

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let videoURL = info[.mediaURL] as? URL {
            print("Here is the URL: \(videoURL)")


            let filename = "Videos/trialVideo.mov"
            Storage.storage().reference().child(filename).putFile(from: videoURL, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print("**** ERROR MESSAGE *** \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }

            }
        }
        videoPicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out in the end, I should have created the URL from an NSURL object (new to this, correct me if that's not the correct terminology)

Updated code:

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let videoURL = info[.mediaURL] as? NSURL {
            print("Here is the URL: \(videoURL)")
            let url: URL = videoURL.absoluteURL!


            let filename = "Videos/trialVideo.mov"
            Storage.storage().reference().child(filename).putFile(from: url, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print("**** ERROR MESSAGE *** \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }

            }
        }
        videoPicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```